# using Etsy's statsD profiler to profile spark jobs

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, profiler

I have been trying to run my spark app with etsy's jvm profiler [https://github.com/etsy/statsd-jvm-profiler to profile my spark app, however I am facing issues with the execution.

When run using with the given command:

`spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.local.dir=/local/spark-scratch-space --conf spark.yarn.queue=streaming --conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-javaagent:statsd-jvm-profiler-2.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar=server=x.x.x.x,port=8086,reporter=InfluxDBReporter,database=profiler,username=profiler,password=profiler,prefix=MySparkAPP,tagMapping=US_Offline' --conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-javaagent:statsd-jvm-profiler-2.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar=server=x.x.x.x,port=8086,reporter=InfluxDBReporter,database=profiler,username=profiler,password=profiler,prefix=MySparkAPP,tagMapping=US_Offline' --class someClass --master yarn-client --num-executors 5 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 2G --jars /local/shprin/statsd-jvm-profiler-2.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar MyApp`

it fails with error:

`Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : statsd-jvm-profiler-2.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
 Error occurred during initialization of VM
 agent library failed to init: instrument`

I have downloaded the precompiled jar from this link:

> wget -qc https://github.com/etsy/statsd-jvm-profiler/releases/download/2.1.0/statsd-jvm-profiler-2.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

I am all new to this, and I am seeking help in understanding what is going wrong, since the spark app if ran without the profiler, runs just fine.

I need pointers to look at and explore to get this fixed.
Any help, suggestions are welcome.

I am using java8 and the spark app is written in scala. And I have already checked the manifest file exists in statsd-jvm-profiler-2.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Resource Manager logs:

```html
Exception from resource manager : 
18/06/12 17:05:04 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Completed container container_e02_1525632635880_0582_01_000012 on host: cluster-nm-1a-d28x-a19182d8.us-east-1.amazon.com (state: COMPLETE, exit status: 1)
18/06/12 17:05:04 WARN yarn.YarnAllocator: Container marked as failed: container_e02_1525632635880_0582_01_000012 on host: cluster-nm-1a-d28x-a19182d8.us-east-1.amazon.com. Exit status: 1. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e02_1525632635880_0582_01_000012
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:545)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
 at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
 at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
 at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1
```

Comment: the issue is resolved, the problem was with "" while declaring spark.executor.extraJavaOptions and spark.driver.extraJavaOptions

Comment: There seems to be a new problem with `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 1 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down`

Comment: LearningNinja, Could you add the final command that you end up solving this issue with ""